# Trigonometry - proving an inequality

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

I came across this question while doing trigonometry. I have tried everything that I could possibly think of, AM/GM, converting it into quadratic equation, conditional identities, solving from RHS, solving from LHS, however, have not gotten anywhere. Please help me!

Question:
In triangle ABC, prove that:
$$(\sin A + \sin B)(\sin B+\sin C)(\sin C+\sin A) \gt \sin A \sin B \sin C$$

Comment: As $0<A<\pi,\sin A>0$ etc. and $$\frac{\sin A+\sin B}2\ge \sqrt{\sin A\sin B}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How exactly did you get that? Where did $\sin c$ go?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: that's only true (aside from the constant) if they are positive. If you already know all of the them are positive, there are easier way (each term on the left is larger than the one on the right). EDIT: opps, had been thinking about $\cos$ the whole time.

Comment: @Cookies, Take the product

Comment: The product of the left hand side? @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @Gina, Nice observation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sin A+\sin B>\sin A,\sin B+\sin C>\sin B,\sin C+\sin A>\sin C$. Take product.

Comment: I see now. Don't know how I missed that... I'm horrible at proof :/

Comment: I love this. One line proof.